# uploadForm url in grails

Tags: grails

I am using the following code:

```
  ${childInstance.firstname}
<br/>
<g:uploadForm url="[action: 'upload', params:[id:childInstance.id]]">
        <input type="file" name="myFile" />
        <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
    </g:uploadForm>
```

The childInstance.firstname is working and giving back the child's first name
but the childInstance.id is passing a string of "index" to my upload controller.

any ideas why?

If I change it to point to another method it works but what not this one?

```
def upload() {
    def childInstance2  = Child.get(params.id)
    def f = request.getFile('myFile')
    if (f == null | f.empty) {
        flash.default = "file cannot be empty"
        errors.getFieldError("cannot be empty")
        return
    }
    def fName = f.getOriginalFilename()
    def picture = new Picture(orgName: fName, urlOrg: "http://localhost/"+fName, user:lookupPerson(), child:childInstance2 )
    f.transferTo(new File('/Users/sagarmichael/Desktop/photoUpload/'+fName))
    picture.save(flush: true, failOnError: true)
    response.sendRedirect("index")
}
```

Comment: your url attribute is a string. Is that a typo?

Comment: Also, shouldn't you use like: `params:[id:${childInstance.id}]` ?

Comment: Doing exactly this works ok for me, at least as far as the actual id being sent to the controller. Are you sure your controller is sending the id to the upload page correctly?  When you view the source of the upload page does the above end up like `<form action="/YourApp/yourController/upload/1" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >` with a valid id at the end up the action?

Comment: And Tiago - when you are in a "Grails-y" context like the params construct already you don't need to wrap with ${}.  Like when you are rendering a link you can do `<g:link params="[sort: 'title', order: 'asc', author: currentBook.author]"
        action="list">Book List</g:link>` without having to do ${currentBook.author}